# Dynamic verbose name of model in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a HelpTicket model, and I want the main Django admin page to show the Verbose Name as `HelpTickets (2 unclosed)` where HelpTicket.objects.count(closed=False) = 2

Is there an easy way of dynamically over-riding the verbose name in this fashion?

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried, but can you assign the meta option verbose_name_plural to a function that combines "Help Tickets" with count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use proxy model here.

```
class ShowHelpTicket(HelpTicket):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name_plural = "Help Tickets ( " + str(HelpTicket.objects.count(closed=False)) + "unclosed )"
```

Here you'll find a nice tutorial. [Using Proxy Models to Customize the Django Admin](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/using-proxy-models-customize-django-admin/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
def update_verbose_name(model_class, name):
    model_class._meta.verbose_name_plural = name
```

to use it:

```
new_name = f"Help Tickets ({HelpTicket.objects.count(closed=False))} unclosed)"
update_verbose_name(HelpTicket, new_name)
```

in your case you could use it with a `post_save` and `post_delete` signal to keep it up to date.